# Blender, Cycles Render, call to function cause app to crash

Tags: c++, crash, blender, renderer

I am trying to get the get the color of each sample during Cycles rendering. In order to do so, I am calling the following function

```
void update_bcd_inputs(int x, int y, float sampleR, float sampleG, float sampleB){

    float current_valueR = sStats->m_meanImage.getValue(bcd::PixelPosition(x, y), 0); // += sampleR;
    float current_valueG = sStats->m_meanImage.getValue(bcd::PixelPosition(x, y), 1); // += sampleG;
    float current_valueB = sStats->m_meanImage.getValue(bcd::PixelPosition(x, y), 2); // += sampleB;
    sStats->m_meanImage.set(x, y, 0, current_valueR + sampleR);
    sStats->m_meanImage.set(x, y, 1, current_valueG + sampleG);
    sStats->m_meanImage.set(x, y, 2, current_valueB + sampleB);
}
```

in blender/intern/cycles/device/device_cpu.cpp

```
void path_trace(DeviceTask &task, RenderTile &tile, KernelGlobals *kg)
{
    float *render_buffer = (float*)tile.buffer;
    int start_sample = tile.start_sample;
    int end_sample = tile.start_sample + tile.num_samples;
    float inv_weight = 1.0f/tile.num_samples;

    for(int sample = start_sample; sample < end_sample; sample++) {
        if(task.get_cancel() || task_pool.canceled()) {
            if(task.need_finish_queue == false)
                break;
        }

        for(int y = tile.y; y < tile.y + tile.h; y++) {
            for(int x = tile.x; x < tile.x + tile.w; x++) {
                path_trace_kernel()(kg, render_buffer,
                                    sample, x, y, tile.offset, tile.stride);

                int step = tile.offset + x + y*tile.stride;
                step *= kernel_data.film.pass_stride;
                float sampleR = *(render_buffer +step);
                float sampleG = *(render_buffer +step +1);
                float sampleB = *(render_buffer +step +2);
                update_bcd_inputs(x, y, sampleR*inv_weight, sampleG*inv_weight, sampleB*inv_weight);
            }
        }

        tile.sample = sample + 1;

        task.update_progress(&tile, tile.w*tile.h);
    }
}
```

SamplesStatisticsImages sStats is an attribute of CPUDevice

```
struct SamplesStatisticsImages
{
    SamplesStatisticsImages() = default;
    SamplesStatisticsImages(int i_width, int i_height, int i_nbOfBins);
    SamplesStatisticsImages(const SamplesStatisticsImages&) = default;
    SamplesStatisticsImages(SamplesStatisticsImages&&) = default;
    SamplesStatisticsImages& operator=(const SamplesStatisticsImages&) = default;
    SamplesStatisticsImages& operator=(SamplesStatisticsImages&&) = default;

    DeepImage<float> m_nbOfSamplesImage;
    DeepImage<float> m_meanImage;
    DeepImage<float> m_covarImage;
    DeepImage<float> m_histoImage;
};
```

Here are the files [DeepImage.hpp](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i14etu31ynnu8x0/DeepImage.hpp?dl=0) and [DeepImage.h](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0bkwywaces7tsyo/DeepImage.h?dl=0).

The problem is that the call to update_bcd_inputs makes Blender to crash without even trying to render an image. I just change the renderer to Cycles, try to add a new material and boom, it crashes.

I figured out it is the set function that is the problem (when I remove it, the app doesn't crash).

Can someone understand why ? I don't have strong C++ skills so I must be missing something.

Here is the [crash log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5vau3j10gwjxc0e/blender_2018-01-02-112721_MacBook-Pro-de-Mkrtich.crash?dl=0) as well.

Thanks !

**Edit**: more precisions

Here is the modified [device_cpu.cpp](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dsp27fnijlp7420/device_cpu_modified.cpp?dl=0).

The `sStats` pointer is initialized with `nullptr` in the CPUDevice constructor

```
CPUDevice(DeviceInfo& info_, Stats &stats_, bool background_)
: Device(info_, stats_, background_),
  texture_info(this, "__texture_info", MEM_TEXTURE),
  histoParams(),
#define REGISTER_KERNEL(name) name ## _kernel(KERNEL_FUNCTIONS(name))
  ...
#undef REGISTER_KERNEL
{
    ...
    sStats = nullptr;
}
```

and then allocated in

```
void thread_render(DeviceTask& task)
{
   ...
   sStats = new bcd::SamplesStatisticsImages(task.w, task.h, histoParams.m_nbOfBins);
   ...
}
```

histoParams is an attribute of CPUDevice as well.

```
struct HistogramParameters
{
    HistogramParameters() :
            m_nbOfBins(20),
            m_gamma(2.2f),
            m_maxValue(2.5f) {}

    int m_nbOfBins;
    float m_gamma; ///< exponent for the exponential size increase of histogram bins
    float m_maxValue;
};
```

Comment: So your adding `update_bcd_inputs` to the CPUDevice class and sStats is also a class property? Do you allocate and initialize it somewhere? or just have the struct as a property and access it in the update func? Maybe also add a copy of your modified `device_cpu.cpp`.

Comment: Thanks @sambler for your reply. I've added some precisions and the modified `device_cpu.cpp` as well

Comment: I solved my problem. When calling addSample, x and y values need to be switched.